# Solving a recursion relation

Tags: recursion

I have the recursion relation $y_{k}=k(2j-k+1)y_{k-1}$

and I would like to solve it to obtain $y_{k}=\frac{k!(2j)!}{(2j-k)!}$.

Can you provide some hints on how I might proceed?

P.S.: $j$ is a constant.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: @Aniket Induction is very useful to prove something you already know. Can it be used to find out the result ($y_k$ as a function of $k$) which is not known in advance? AS OP says, he needs to solve, not to proove the solution.

Comment: @CiaPan Consider $P(k): y_{k}=\frac{k!(2j)!}{(2j-k)!}$ and use $y_{k}=k(2j-k+1)y_{k-1}$ to prove $P(k+1)$ is true. Here it is not given but you have to consider that $y_0=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying the both sides of
$$y_k=k(2j-k+1)y_{k-1}$$
by $\frac{(2j-k)!}{k!}$ gives
$$\frac{(2j-k)!}{k!}y_k=\frac{(2j-k+1)!}{(k-1)!}y_{k-1},$$
i.e.
$$z_k=z_{k-1}$$
where
$$z_k=\frac{(2j-k)!}{k!}y_k$$

So, we have 
$$\frac{(2j-k)!}{k!}y_k=z_k=z_{k-1}=\cdots =z_1=z_0=\frac{(2j-0)!}{0!}y_0=(2j)!,$$
i.e.
$$y_k=\frac{k!(2j)!}{(2j-k)!}$$

Comment: But aren't you starting from what has to be found...?

Comment: @CiaPan: No. I added the details.

Comment: mathlove, it will be helpful if you edit your post to provide the complete answer

Comment: @failexam:  See what I added.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that $y_{0}=1$.

All right, then, we have

$$\frac{y_k}{y_0} = \prod_{i = 1}^k \frac{y_i}{y_{i-1}}$$

$$y_k = \prod_{i=1}^{k} i(2j-i+1)$$

$$y_k = \bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{k} i\bigg) \bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{k} (2j-i+1)\bigg)$$

$$y_k = (k!) \bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{k} (2j-(i-1))\bigg)$$

$$y_k = (k!) \frac{(2j)!}{(2j-k)!}$$